# Get the width of li and add it to ul using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the style attribute 'width' from li and adding it to ul.

My html code is

```
<div id="carousel_team" class="glide">
<ul class="slides" style="opacity: 1; width: 1464px;">
<li class="slide first active" data-slide="1" style="width: 244px;">1</l1>
<li class="slide" data-slide="2" style="width: 244px;">2</l1>
</ul>
</div>
```

And jQuery is

```
 var b = a.current();
 var ul = $("#carousel_team ul");
 var clicked_slide = ul.find("[data-slide='" + b + "']");
 var clicked_slide_width = ul.li:[data-slide='" + b + "']").attr("width");
 alert(clicked_slide_width);
```

I am getting 'Undefined'. The value of b is fine in jquery but for some reason I can't get the attribute width value.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have syntax errors

Comment: hmm...yes in this line ul.li:[data-slide='" + b + "']").attr("width");

Comment: I tried with ul.li[data-slide='" + b + "']").attr("width") and still getting undefined.

Comment: Could you please explain more detailed about what you are trying to do - are you trying to take the width of the current slide and add it to the `ul`?

Comment: @ViktorMaksimov yes I want to take the width of current slide and add it to the ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script:

```
_slider = $("#carousel_team ul");
_current = _slider.find('.active');
_slider.width(_slider.width() + _current.width());
```

Answer (score 0):

This would take the width from `li` for the `data-slide` attr and append it to `ul`

```
var dataSlide = 1;
$("ul").attr("style",$("li[data-slide=" + dataSlide + "]").attr("style"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27wL3mkq/

Updated :

```
dataSlide = 2;
$("ul").css("width",parseInt($("li[data-slide=" + dataSlide + "]").css("width").replace("px",""))  + 
     parseInt($("ul").css("width").replace("px","")));
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass the data-slide value to li.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to get the width of li based on data-slide value so if the data-slide value is 2 then I would like to get the width of second li.

Comment: Updated the answer. Try again

Comment: the ul is now getting updated with the li width but it removed the previous width. For eg if previous ul width is 100px then I would like to add 244px and the result should be 344px. But now the ul width has become 244px